# Customize moreNavigationController

Tags: iphone, sdk, uitabbarcontroller, customization

I am trying to customize the moreNavigationController in a UITabBarController. I have been reading a lot of posts and guides to style this and I have managed to change the tint color of the navigation bar and the background color of the table view but there are still a few things that I would like to customize.

I have changed the tint color and the background like this:

```
tabcontroller.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    tabcontroller.moreNavigationController.topViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tableview-background-blue.png"]];
    tabcontroller.moreNavigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tableview-background-blue.png"]];
```

I would like to change the seperate color (the border) of the UITableView. I would also like to change the tint color of the navigation bar which appears when clicking "Edit". Also it would be great if I could change the language of the whole thing (the "More" and the "Edit" tab and so on)

Would these changes be possible and if so, do you know how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't change the names of this tabs, which are predefined. I'm taking about the Edit button & the more tab.

Comment: If you want more customising check out three20 https://github.com/facebook/three20. Its the same interface the facebook app uses.